# stack trace and variable values

Tags: android

Is it possible to get variable values included in a stack trace?   I have just started using bugsense which emails the stacktrace to me and I wonder if there is some way in my code to put the variable values into the stacktrace output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default, you have to do it by yourself:

The stack trace will only tell you about the involved line of code (where the `Exception` is thrown) and the execution stack.

But nothing prevents you from catching the `Exception` and to include some debug information in the message:

```
try {
   ...the code...
}
catch (Throwable t) {
   // Here, we catch any Throwable (Exception but also Error such as OutOfMemory 
   // or NoClassDefFound), which is *absolutely not suitable* for 
   // anything else than debugging.
   // You can (should, actually) make this catch statement more specific 
   // depending of the Exception or Error you are facing

   // Dump your variables here:
   final String message = "myVar=" + myVar; 

   // The statement below rethrows the original Throwable and adds your
   // own message to it
   throw new RuntimeException(message, t); 
}
```

Or to put a breakpoint in the `catch { }` statement to inspect the state of your application at that stage, but as I understood it may not be applicable in the case you are describing.

(By the way, I suggest you add the tag "Java" to your question. This way it will also be visible by the Java community of StackOverflow)